# Why Python version 3.10 does not support starred expressions in subscriptions

Tags: python, subscription, python-3.10

for example

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones([1, 2, 3])
b = 1, 2
```

In Python 3.10 I cannot use `a[0,*b]` It has to be `a[(0,*b)]` And I can use `c = [0,*b]` `a[*c]` which is `a[0,1,2]`

I find it has been changed on Python 3.11 so I can use it.

Comment: Not supporting some syntax isn't a bug.

Comment: @user2357112 OK, I will change the expression if you do not like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This change is a part of PEP-646 and it's described here: https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/#change-1-star-expressions-in-indexes

And the syntax with parentheses, as you showed, was allowed before.